# Can't load data to TableView

Tags: java, javafx-2, fxml

I can't load data into table. I have class `Player` with `name`, `lastName`, etc. I want to insert `name`, `lastname` into table player over textfield.

```
public class CoreAppFXMLController implements Initializable {

@FXML
private Button addBtn;
@FXML
private Button deleteBtn;
@FXML
private Tab playersTab;
@FXML
private Tab coachesTab;
@FXML
private TextField playerNameFld;
@FXML
private TextField playerLNFld;
@FXML
private TextField playerNumberFld;
@FXML
private TextField playerPointsFld;
@FXML
private ChoiceBox<String> positionCb;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Player, String> playerNameCol;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Player, String> playerLNCol;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Player, String> playerNumberCol;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Player, String> playerPointsCol;
@FXML
private TableView<Player> playerTable;

ObservableList<Player> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

public class Player {

    private String name;
    private String lastName;
    private String number;
    private String points;

    public Player(String name, String lastName, String number, String points) {
        this.name = name;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.number = number;
        this.points = points;

    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public String getPoints() {
        return points;
    }

    public void setPoints(String points) {
        this.points = points;
    }

}

/**
 * Initializes the controller class.
 */
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    positionCb.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList("PLAYMAKER",
            "SHOOTER", "WING", "CENTER", "CENTER-WING"));

    playerNameCol
            .setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Player, String>(
                    "name"));
    playerLNCol
            .setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Player, String>(
                    "lastName"));
    playerNumberCol
            .setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Player, String>(
                    "number"));
    playerPointsCol
            .setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Player, String>(
                    "points"));

    playerTable.setItems(data);

}

public void addBtnAction(ActionEvent event) {
    data.add(new Player(playerNameFld.getText(), playerLNFld.getText(),
            playerNumberFld.getText(), playerPointsFld.getText()));
    playerNameFld.clear();
    playerLNFld.clear();
    playerNumberFld.clear();
    playerPointsFld.clear();

}

public void deleteBtnAction(ActionEvent event) {

}
```

}

I am doing exactly same thing as shown here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/table-view.htm#CJAGAAEE

But I can't get it to work. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Are your `TableColumn`s added to the `TableView` in the FXML file? Can you show the FXML code for that?

Comment: This is the FXML of the table http://pastie.org/9103936

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not exactly the same as the example and if you're using Java 7, then it might not work the same regardless. Try setting up your `Player` class to use `SimpleStringProperty` for the member variables and then add a `*Property()` method for each of them that returns the member. For example:

```
public class Player
{
    private SimpleStringProperty name;

    public Player(String name)
    {
        this.name.set(name);
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty nameProperty() { return name; }
    public String getName() { return name.get(); }
    public void setName(String name) { this.name.set(name); }
}
```

Try that and add in the rest of your members the same way.

Comment: Thank you, it works. I still don't get it how is TextField actually connected with column :)

Comment: It isn't. The column is connected to a property in the `Player` class. Every time a button press creates a new `Player` instance in the `data` list, the table is notified about the change to the list and the table loads the new `Player`. Each column then reflects the value of that new `Player` based on the member name you provided when you created the column's `CellValueFactory`. Once the column is connected to the property, it listens for changes and responds accordingly. It's all about binding. Study up on JavaFX properties [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/binding/jfxpub-binding.htm).